# How do I specify a string to display in the Ubuntu software-center when creating a package with dpkg-deb?

Tags: software-center, dpkg, deb

When I open *.deb packages downloaded from the internet in the Ubuntu software-center, it displays a "nice" name for the package (including upper- and lowercase, spaces, special characters, ...).

When I create a *.deb package from binaries only using `dpkg-deb -b`, Ubuntu Software Center displays the "technical" package name (the one specified at the `Package:` field in the `control` file, limited to lowercase only, no spaces, ...).

Is there any way to provide a string different from the "technical" package name (including upper- and lowercase, spaces, special characters, ...) for display in the Ubuntu software Center?

Unfortunately, this can not be done via the short description (that is displayed below the "technical" name, but not replacing it).

Answer (score 0):

I think that is specified on the `description` field(short description) on the `control` file. Take a look at [this](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#control):

```
...
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: <insert up to 60 chars description>  <-- Here comes the "fancy" name
  <insert long description, indented with spaces>
```